# Parsing 2 text files using cmd or batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to parse 2 text files and make one with information from both files using cmd or batch, is it possible without using any other program or vbscript? Here is the example: `number.txt` contains

```
ren 01.mp3
ren 02.mp3
ren 03.mp3
```

and so on...

`names.txt` contains

```
Chapter_00_Introduction.mp3
Chapter_01_This_is_Chapter_01.mp3
Chapter_02_This_is_Chapter_02.mp3
Chapter_03_This_is_Chapter_03.mp3
```

and so on...

What I'd like is to produce a third file (output.txt) with this content

```
ren 01.mp3 Chapter_00_Introduction.mp3
ren 02.mp3 Chapter_01_This_is_Chapter_01.mp3
ren 03.mp3 Chapter_02_This_is_Chapter_02.mp3
```

and yes, the names are mismatched (`01.mp3` is actually the introduction, `02.mp3` is the chapter 1 and so on).

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Number.txt) do (
   For /f "tokens=*" %%b in (Names.txt) Do (Echo %%a%%b.mp3>>output.txt)
)
Exit
```

The result is

```
Ren 01.mp3 Chapter_00_Introduction.mp3
Ren 01.mp3 Chapter_01_This_is_chapter_02.mp3
Ren 01.mp3 Chapter_03__This_is_chapter_03.mp3
Ren 01.mp3 Chapter_04__This_is_chapter_04.mp3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
< Names.txt (
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Number.txt) do (
      set /P name=
      Echo %%a !name!
   )
) >output.txt
Exit
```

Comment: one result is `ren 01.mp3Chapter_00_Introduction.mp3.mp3`, just change to `Echo %%a !name!` :)

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" number.txt') do set "$%%a=%%b"
(for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" names.txt') do echo !$%%a! %%~b)>endresult.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing this as a homework or an exerciese, an alternative is to use [paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_%28Unix%29) utility to join files horizontally:

Let's say file1 is:

```
ren 01.mp3
ren 02.mp3
ren 03.mp3
```

And file2 is:

```
Chapter_00_Introduction.mp3
Chapter_01_This_is_Chapter_01.mp3
Chapter_02_This_is_Chapter_02.mp3
```

If you run:

```
paste -d ' ' file1 file2 > endresult
```

This will create the endresult file :

```
ren 01.mp3 Chapter_00_Introduction.mp3
ren 02.mp3 Chapter_01_This_is_Chapter_01.mp3
ren 03.mp3 Chapter_02_This_is_Chapter_02.mp3
```